# Automatically open Finder when disk image is mounted

Tags: finder, disk-utility

I created a Disk Image (.dmg) with Disk Utility with the APFS filesystem. When i open the .dmg it gets mounted, and i can go to finder and manually open it.

How do i make Finder automatically open a new window with the .dmg contents when i open/mount the .dmg?

(macOS Catalina, 10.15)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a test, I created a 100 MB APFS disk image and saved it to the default location, in my **Documents** folder. I then unmounted the disk image, as it needed to be unmounted to test what I did next.

Next, in **Automator**, I created a new **Folder Action**, while setting **Folder Action receives files and folders to** `Volumes`. I did this by clicking **Choose folder** > **Other…** and then pressed **⇧⌘G** to bring up the **Go to the folder:** *sheet*. I then typed in `/Volumes` and clicked the **Go** button, followed by the **Choose** button.

Next I added an **Open Finder Items** *action* and saved the **Folder Action** as e.g. **Open Mounted Disk**

From **Finder**, I then doubled-clicked the **APSF.dmg** file and when it was mounted, it opened a new **Finder** window to the *root* of the mounted disk image.

---

- Note that when the disk image opened, I was prompted with a message **"FolderActionsDispatcher" would like to access files in your Documents folder**, to which I clicked the **OK** button. This created an entry in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Files and Folders** as **FolderActionsDispatcher** with a **[√] Documents Folder** checkbox.
- The e.g. **Open Mounted Disk.workflow** was by default saved to:

  ```
  /Users/$USER/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions/
  ```

[image]

Comment: It works indeed, thank you!  And thanks for the very clear description too.